# Database inserts are combined?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a script which inserts into two seperate database tables: ingredients, and directions.
For the first, I use `$this->db->query($sql)`, and for the second: `$this->db->query($sql2)` (I'm using CodeIgniter).
Here's my code:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = $this->input->post($key);
        $directions = $this->input->post('directions');
        $ingredientQTY = $this->input->post('ingredientQTY');
        $measurements = $this->input->post('measurements');
        $ingredientNAME = $this->input->post('ingredientNAME');
        $ingredientsROW[] = array($ingredientQTY, $measurements, $ingredientNAME);

        //For inserting ingredients
        for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
            $rows[] = array(
                'ingredientamount'      => $ingredientQTY[$i],
                'ingredientType'        => $measurements[$i],
                'ingredientname'        => $ingredientNAME[$i],
                'recipe_id'             => $recipe_id,
                'order'                 => $i + 1,
                'user_id'               => $user_id
            );
            $sql = "INSERT `ingredients` (`ingredientamount`,`ingredientType`,`ingredientname`,`recipe_id`, `listOrder`, `user_id`) VALUES ";
            $coma = '';
            foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
                $sql .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
                $coma = ', ';
            }

        }
        $this->db->query($sql);//Insert Query for ingredients

        //For inserting directions
        for ($i = 0, $count = count($directions); $i < $count; $i++) {
            $rows[] = array(
                'direction'     => $directions[$i],
                'recipe_id'             => $recipe_id,
                'order'                 => $i + 1,
                'user_id'               => $user_id
            );
            $sql2 = "INSERT `directions` (`direction`,`recipe_id`,`listOrder`,`user_id`) VALUES ";
            $coma = '';
            foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
                $sql2 .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
                $coma = ', ';
            }
        }
        $this->db->query($sql2);    //Insert Query for directions
        break;
    }
```

I should have two seperate sql statements, but for some reason they are combined into, and generate the following error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

INSERT `directions` (`direction`,`recipe_id`,`listOrder`,`user_id`) VALUES ('1','Bunch','Cilantro','1','1','1'), ('3','Cup','Sugar','1','2','1'), ('First, combine the cilantro and sugar','1','1','1'), ('then eat. ','1','2','1')
```

There should be a INSERT `ingredients` as well, but its values get combined into the `INSERT directions` statement.

Why would the two SQL statements be combined?

Comment: @PreetSangha, There are 2 in count($directions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of your code builds `$rows` to insert all ingredients, then the second half builds `$rows` to insert all directions, but it never clears out `$rows` inbetween. When you go to do directions the ingredients are still in the array.

In addition, I think you're calling the SQL too often. Your `for $i` loop and `foreach $rows` loop shouldn't be nested; they should be one followed by the other. Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
  $rows[] = array(
    'ingredientamount' => $ingredientQTY[$i],
    'ingredientType'   => $measurements[$i],
    'ingredientname'   => $ingredientNAME[$i],
    'recipe_id'        => $recipe_id,
    'order'            => $i + 1,
    'user_id'          => $user_id
  );
} // <-- FIRST FOR LOOP SHOULD END HERE

$sql = "INSERT `ingredients` (`ingredientamount`,`ingredientType`,`ingredientname`,`recipe_id`, `listOrder`, `user_id`) VALUES ";
$coma = '';
foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
  $sql .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
  $coma = ', ';
}
//  } <-- FIRST FOR LOOP USED TO END HERE; PROBABLY NOT RIGHT

$this->db->query($sql);//Insert Query for ingredients

$rows = array(); // <-- Clear out $rows to reuse it for directions
```

With the `$rows` array cleared out you can then go on to the directions. As with the ingredients, put the loops one after another rather than nested.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql2 = "INSERT directions ('direction','recipe_id','listOrder','user_id') VALUES ";
```

the first set of brackets specifies 4 columns, but you try to insert 6 values.

fixed code:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO directions VALUES ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting the values from the rows array though, so there is actually 4 columns and 4 values, so this doesn't work.

Comment: The 6 values that come from the error are actually supposed to be inserted to the Ingredients statement, but for some reason get added to the insert into directions instead

Comment: change `directions` in `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO directions VALUES ";` to `ingredients` :)